# Git - Add all new files in the repo

Tags: git

I'm trying to automate an update process. The process is basically:

1. Check out repo A
2. Check out repo B
3. Run a process in repo B that updates/creates a bunch of files
4. Copy files into repo A
5. Compile repo A and make sure it doesn't fail
6. Commit changes into repo A and repo B
7. Push changes to the remote server.

Everything is working as expected except step 6. I can commit the changes, but how do I commit any new files? I tried `git add .` as I've read elsewhere but that doesn't catch all the new files in all the sub directories. Is there an easy way to do a "Add all new files"?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Take a look [here](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-add.html). Perhaps you're interested in `git add -u` or `git add -A`.

Answer (score 31):

```
git add -A
```

will stage all modifications to the working tree. Add really means "include in the index" or "add changes to the index".

Answer (score 6):

You can use `git add -A` As already mentioned or the long subcommand `git add --all`

Answer (score 2):

I know I'm late to the party here, but you can also do `git -a -m "commit message here"`. This takes care of adding files as well as committing them in one command. I use this command pretty heavily.